# Counting total of even in a BST

Tags: c++, tree

I'm trying to count total of leaves that have even numbers in a BST.

> Example: root--> 2 4 6 8 9
> Output: 4 leaf that have even numbers.

Here is what I have done:

```
struct BSTNode
{
    BSTNode* left;
    BSTNode* right;
    int data;
};
        
int CountingTotalEven(BST* root)
{
    int count = 0;
    count++;
    CountingTotalEven(BST* root);
    return count; 
}
```

My program output wrong number, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Which is your actual output and the desired output? Are you trying to do it with recursion? It seems that you are missing something `CountingTotalEven` declare to 0 the count each time and never pass it to the next call so the count will be always 1.

Comment: yes i use recursion

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

```
    int count = 0;
    count++;
    CountingTotalEven(BST* root);
    return count;
```

There are three main issues in this code currently. Firstly, you're initializing count in your recursive function as a non-static variable. So what happens is count gets initialized as 0 every time this recursive function is called.

Secondly, you've called the recursive function on the root again. What you want to do is call the function recursively for its right and left subtrees(read: Tree Traversals).

Thirdly, you're not checking if the value is actually even.Change your function to

```
    static int count = 0;
    if(count%2 == 0)
        count++;
    CountingTotalEven(root->left);
    CountingTotalEven(root->right);
    return count;
```